# Airflow Docker Image Not Handling Python Modules As Expected

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I'm running `puckel/docker-airflow` in AWS using `docker-compose` and a slightly modified `docker-compose.yml` and it's not picking up Python modules as I expect it to, I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong or if my expecatations are incorrect. When I try to use Python modules, such as `smart_open` in my DAG files I get an error:

```
webserver_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 413, in process_file
webserver_1  |     m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
webserver_1  |     module = _load(spec)
webserver_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 684, in _load
webserver_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
webserver_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
webserver_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/mysql_etl.py", line 11, in <module>
webserver_1  |     import smart_open
webserver_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smart_open'
```

However, I have `smart_open` listed in my `requirements.txt`, I have my `requirements.txt` file mounted in my `docker-compose.yml`, and it appears to get loaded as expected:

```
webserver_1  | Collecting smart_open (from -r /requirements.txt (line 3))
webserver_1  |   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/37/c0/25d19badc495428dec6a4bf7782de617ee0246a9211af75b302a2681dea7/smart_open-1.8.4.tar.gz (63kB)
```

Alternatively, the error goes away when I build the docker image specifying `smart_open` using 
`--build-arg PYTHON_DEPS="smart_open"`

I'm not modifying `entrypoint.sh` from `puckel/docker-airflow`, as far as I can see the default behavior performs a `pip install --user -r requirements.txt` and is working as expected.

So: is there something I need to do differently for my DAG files to have access to the Python modules specified in `requirements.txt` or do I simply have build my Docker image with all desired modules? Thanks for any insight on this!

Comment: Can you check whether webserver_1 has any errors reported with pip install (Not necessarily for smart_open) in logs? If one package failed to install, there's a possibility that all installs failed.

Comment: Thank you! I checked, there were errors but resolving them did not change the behavior. I connected to my webserver and worker as airflow user and verified that the Python environments have the modules available as expected using `help("modules")`

Comment: I personally use a heavily modified version of the same and haven't faced this issue. Can you add `RUN python3 -m pip install setuptools && python3 -m pip install smart_open` to your docker file and try?